# How to auto map pojos in java

Tags: dictionary, mapping, automapper

I want to use a java framework that auto maps between my simple objects, and I need a recommendation.

I have listed the following requests from it:

1. If the values are loaded through reflection,
   I want it to cache the mapping so it would not go through the full process next time.
2. Quick conversion of mapping.
3. Minimum code when attributes have the same name on both objects.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Orika](http://code.google.com/p/orika) ,
here is a [thesis](http://dspace.cc.tut.fi/dpub/bitstream/handle/123456789/21976/Ratamaa.pdf?sequence=1) comparing various Java mapping framework based on features, performance and scalability.